# There are many UX Maturity Models, but are there any UX Maturity Roadmaps?

Tags: ux-integration, organizations

I've done a lot of thinking lately about building UX-awareness, UX practices, and Design Thinking at large organizations.

There are lots of different "[UX Maturity Models](https://shanegryzko.wordpress.com/oddly-specific/ux-maturity-models/)" online that describe this process. I've found them helpful because while their details vary, they all seem to agree with these main concepts:

- that it is **valuable** to mature the UX of an organization,
- that there's a **common order** in which UX practices are matured, and
- that it takes a **long time** to progress.

Unfortunately, they all seem to lack the following:

- A **detailed roadmap** for moving an organization through this maturity process.

I know that this is way easier said than done and that every company is different. However, the [Software Assurance Maturity Model (SAMM)](http://www.opensamm.org/roadmap/), a similar concept but for software security as opposed to UX, does have such a roadmap. The SAMM roadmap is split into about a dozen different areas. Each area has Objectives and specific Activities listed for three levels of maturity (1-3).

Below is an excerpt from SAMM showing the levels of maturity for the Strategy and Metrics area.

[image: SAMM Strategy & Metrics maturity levels]

What's great about this is that it allows you to actually measure your maturity and that it shows what is required to move it to the next level.

**Are there any UX Maturity Roadmaps available?**

Comment: I think you will have to create ux maturity roadmaps based on the ux maturity of an organisation and how they want to improve their maturity over a period of time given the resources available. Not something that you can easily define when there are many unknowns and variables to take into account, but a very interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: I'm not aware of any "sanctioned" models, but I bet a lot of us here could draft a prototype off the top of our head.

Comment: @plainclothes Let's do it! Community wiki created. http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/98478/34088

Answer (score 1):

## No such models exist, so let's make one here

Might not be the best format for this type of thing (I want to use tables!) but it can't hurt to try.

I'll base this maturity roadmap on the fantastic [CUBI model](https://uxmag.com/articles/cubi-a-user-experience-model-for-project-success).

[image: CUBI Model]

### Areas

*I've arbitrarily picked 4 groups of 3 areas to mirror the SAMM model but feel free to add, remove, or modify areas as you see fit.*

- Content

  - Content Strategy
  - Information Architecture
  - Visual Design
- User Goals

  - User Personas
  - User Interviews and Research
  - User Journeys
- Business Goals

  - Requirements Gathering
  - Business Research
  - Marketing
- Interaction

  - Usability Testing
  - Development
  - Wireframes/Prototypes

### Maturity Levels

*To keep things simple, we won't go into the specific objectives and activities here. Let's just give a tweet-sized description of what it means to be a 1, a 2, and a 3. 0s have been left out for brevity because they're hopefully self-explanatory.*

**Content: Content Strategy**

1. x
2. x
3. x

**Content: Information Architecture**

1. x
2. x
3. x

**Content: Visual Design**

1. x
2. x
3. x

**User Goals: User Personas**

1. [Proto-personas](https://uxmag.com/articles/using-proto-personas-for-executive-alignment) have been created based on assumptions about users but not validated with user research.
2. Personas have been created and validated but are not regularly used by the whole team or have not been updated recently.
3. Personas are available for the whole team to refer to and are updated regularly with new learnings.

**User Goals: User Interviews and Research**

1. x
2. x
3. x

**User Goals: User Journeys**

1. x
2. x
3. x

**Business Goals: Requirements Gathering**

1. x
2. x
3. x

**Business Goals: Business Research**

1. x
2. x
3. x

**Business Goals: Marketing**

1. x
2. x
3. x

**Interaction: Usability Testing**

1. Hallway usability testing: Occasionally, the team will test the product on each other, similar to the methods described [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/news/fog0000000118.html).
2. Guerilla usability testing: Regular, simple usability tests are performed, similar to the methods described [here](http://www.sensible.com/rsme.html).
3. Formal usability testing: Regular, more rigorous usability tests are performed. (*is there a good link for this?*)

**Interaction: Development**

1. x
2. x
3. x

**Interaction: Wireframes/Prototypes**

1. x
2. x
3. x

Comment: I would approach the roadmap as though I was a consultant coming into a completely inexperienced company. I'll use software as an example (since that's what I know). If they've just been building a product off the cuff and are ready to scale, what do they need to do and in what order? I'd argue that step one is building up a storehouse of a data about users and software analytics. They'll need to develop a research and analytics department. Shortly thereafter, they'll need product strategy and UX to build personas and user stories and start acting on that data. ... and so on.

Comment: It's definitely tough trying to make this general enough for a wide audience but specific enough to be actionable. SAMM did that well. @plainclothes are you saying that this answer is currently structured more as "12 areas in parallel" whereas you'd like the roadmap to be a bit more sequential?

Comment: to some extent, I  think sequential steps is the easiest way to communicate it. And probably the most realistic, though some progression happens in rapid or parallel succession.

Comment: @plainclothes Yes that's fair. I think I'll start fleshing out this parallel model and add a note saying not all areas have to be worked on simultaneously. If you want to post a separate answer for a more sequential approach, perhaps based on something like [NNg's model](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/usability-maturity-stages-1-4/) but with more actionable advice, please do so :D